# ng2-Chart: can we show the tooltip data of pie chart on load?

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

As shown in the image , can i fix the tool tip data to be shown all the time and not just on the hover? is this possible?

[image]

this is the code i am taking the reference from: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-pie-template

Comment: If you want to show the tooltip at all times so you can see the amounts you might want to think about using a different chart type like a bar chart. Because they are way better for your purpose

Comment: @LeeLenalee , That's exactly what i said :( . but i don't know why they only want pie chart and in that particular manner.

Answer (score 0):

found a plugin to do so :https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo/

```
public chartOptions: any = {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          labels: [
            {
              render: 'label',
              arc: true,
              fontSize: 14,
              fontStyle: 'bold',
              fontColor: '#000',
              position: 'outside'
            },
            {
              render: 'value',
              fontSize: 14,
              fontStyle: 'bold',
              fontColor: '#000',
              fontFamily: '"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace'
            }
          ]
        },
      };
```